# Как поместить WrapPanel в ScrollViewer?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Как поместить WrapPanel в ScrollViewer?

Пытался реализовать вот так, но компилятор ругается:

```
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <ScrollViewer>
                                            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                                        </ScrollViewer>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

Весь код:

                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}">
                                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="200"
                                                    Margin="5">
                                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}"></Image>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="White"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
```

Желаемый эффект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем WrapPanel, если есть ScrollViewer? Какой лэйаут вам нужен?

Comment: @VladD, дополнил вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня работает так:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="..." ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    ...
```